# Trouble with simple low-pass filters

Tags: matlab, frequency, lowpass-filter

I'm trying to get a very basic handle on low-pass filters. Be warned, I'm a complete beginner to filters with some experience in MATLAB. I looked around for answers, but couldn't find anything that was sufficiently simple.

How would I design and plot the response of a filtered 20Hz signal through a 400Hz cutoff using a low-pass filter? The 20Hz signal is not noisy data, it is to be generated by the computer. I do have the Signal Processing Toolbox.

I used the command

```
d = designfilt('lowpassfir','CutoffFrequency',400,'SampleRate',20)
```

but it told me I did not have enough input arguments. I attempted to remedy the situation in MATLAB's digital filter assistant, and that generated the line

```
d = designfilt('lowpassfir', 'FilterOrder', 10, 'CutoffFrequency',100,'SampleRate', 20, 'Window', 'hamming');
```

which was errored out by the following:

```
Frequency specifications must be between 0 and 10.
```

I also fear that the 'hamming' specification may unfavorably alter my result from a hand calculation of the signal attenuation.

Comment: Hm, maybe the first question should be what it is you want to do, and *why*. You say you don't know anything about filters, so i'm wondering. Is this just for learning or do you want to do something productive (supposedly that learning is not productive ;) )
If you want to do digital signal processing, you also need to know your sample rate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's for a class, where the problem statement was "plot the low frequency signal (20Hz in this case) due to the low pass filter with the specified cutoff." There has been no mention of a sampling frequency. Obviously my primary interest lies in completing the problem, but I need to know how to interpret this problem in terms of a filter design for future use (I do occasionally work with noisy filters, but for my purposes I've just used FFT and a simple Gaussian filter.

Comment: What is the exact formulation of the problem? The answer highly depends on  the given signal. For example, a 20 Hz sine wave will not be affected by a 400 Hz lowpass filter.
If no sample rate is given, than i would guess they are talking about analog signals (or an analog treatment of the signals), but that is not for sure.